# Building a calculator using html JavaScript which takes values from two input tags and returns final answer on clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html

Calculator which takes numbers written in input tag by users and then add them on clicking submit and shows result.

```
var numOne = document.getElementById("first");
var numTwo = 
document.getElementById("second");
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var added = document.getElementById("answer");

submit.addEventListner( function(){
var one = numOne.value;
var two = numTwo.value;
added.innerHTML = one + two;
```

})
Please tell me the mistake

Comment: Please ask specific queries with code as example otherwise you will not be able to get any help.

Comment: You probably want to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Voting to close.

Comment: plenty of full calclulator codes in other questions here if you mind to search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<input type="number" id="a">
<input type="number" id="b">
<input type="submit" id="submit">

<h1 id="answer"></h1>
```

Javascript

```
var submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
var answer = document.querySelector('#answer');

submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var a = document.querySelector('#a').value;
    var b = document.querySelector('#b').value;
    answer.textContent = Number(a) + Number(b);
})
```

This is pretty straightforward but can be expanded upon to validate input properly and do other calculations.

Firstly, if you take a look at the html, you can see two number input fields and one submit button. Note that I have given them all IDs so that we can select them in our JS file. I have also provided an empty h1 element in which we will display the answer of our calculation.

In the JS file we are just listening for a click event on the submit button at which point, we capture the values entered into your input fields and add them together after coercing their type to numbers.

Finally, we return the sum of these values to the DOM as the textContent of the h1 element with id="answer"